# Consuming azure event hub events in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amqp, azure-eventhub, aws-serverless

I'm trying to consume events that are published to a Azure event hub hosted by a third party, the service that consumes these events is an AWS based architecture.

What is the best way to consume event hub messages in aws services?

Would my only options be:

- Set up an EC2 with an application that continuously processes the event hub messages
- Have a scheduled lambda that processes messages, picking up where the last invocation left off

Both options using this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-node-get-started-send

Is there any other way to accomplish this? The goal would be to somehow have event hub trigger a service like lambda directly.

Comment: Have the Azure event hub trigger an AWS API gateway via HTTPS, which proxies the request to the lambda?

Comment: @Paolo I couldn't see anywhere that said event hub could trigger API gateway, do you know if that's definitely possible?